# How to load the sequence of image in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

```
import S1-T1-C.00000
Image.open('C:/Users/Vims/Desktop/7th sem/ISA/Lab_1/sequence/sequence')
```

I have set of image sequence or video. I would like to load in the python code. How can I do it? After that I will do background subtraction of an image.

The sequence of image is from S1-T1-C.00000 to S1-T1-C.00999.

Comment: `import` is only to load module with code, not images.

Comment: use `os.listdir(directory)` to get all filenames in directory, and use `for`-loop to create full path to every file `os.path.join( directory, filename)` and load every file. And you could keep them in list.

Comment: if you know names then you could use `for`-loop with values `0...999` and use `string formatting` or `f-string` to create filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all situations you need `for`-loop.

If you don't know names then you can use `os.listdir(folder)` to get all filenames in folder (you can also use `sorted()` to have them in correct order) and then you have to read every image separatelly

```
all_images = []

folder = "C:/folder/with/images"

for filename in sorted(os.listdir(folder)):

    full_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)

    img = Image.open(full_path)
    all_images.append( img )
```

If you know filenames then you can use `string formatting` or `f-string`

```
all_images = []

folder = "C:/folder/with/images"

for number in range(0, 1_000):

    filename = f"S1-T1-C.{number:05}"
    full_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)

    img = Image.open(full_path)
    all_images.append( img )
```

---

**BTW:**

If you have images in many folders then it may need nested `for`-loops

```
all_images = []

base_folder = "C:/folder/with/images"

for foldername in os.listdir(base_folder):

    folder = os.path.join(base_folder, foldername) 

    for filename in sorted(os.listdir(folder)):

        full_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)

        img = Image.open(full_path)
        all_images.append( img )
```

---

If there can be some other files/folders then every version may need some `if/else` to filter files/folders

---

There is also module `glob` which can use `*` to match many files/folders

```
all_filenames = glob.glob("*/S1-T1-C.*")

for filename in all_filenames:
    # ... code ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a very detailed response. 
 _**`
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os, sys
from PIL import Image
import glob

all_images = []

folder = "C:/Users/Vims/Desktop/7th sem/ISA/Lab_1/sequence/sequence"

for filename in sorted(os.listdir(folder)):
    full_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    img = Image.open(full_path)
    all_images.append( img )
    img.show(img)`** _ 

How to open in only one window or tab? Every time a new tab or window is getting open. I want to make as video because it is a sequence of images.

Comment: if you use `cv2` then you should see it in every tutorial for `cv2` - use `cv2.imshow(window_name, img)` (and `cv2.waitKey(0)`) and it will always open in the same window (if you always use the same `window_name`). And then you should also use `cv2` to load image. OR you will have to convert `Pillow.Image` to `numpy.array` and convert colors `RGB` to `BGR`

Comment: if you have new problem then you should create new question on nee page - you will have new space for code and description, and code will be more readable.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Vims/Desktop/7th sem/ISA/Lab_1/sequence/sequence\\S1-T1-C.00000'

What is this error means ? How can I correct it?

Comment: error means it can't find this file - maybe you shouldn't mix / and \\ . OR maybe you created it in wrong why. Do you really have `sequence/sequence` on disk? maybe you should have only one `sequence` in path.